# Why is the inverse of a vector a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

I was doing some simple exercises with vectors and I wondered what the inverse of lets say the vector $\vec v = \vec i + \vec j $ is.

I multiplied with the denominator and numerator with $\vec w = \vec i - \vec j$, but realized the denominator becomes zero.

I used Geogebra to see what will happen if I do this. The thing is when a vector is inverted, the result is a complex number. Why is this so?

Comment: there is no notion of the "inverse" of a vector in general.  Vectors have additive inverses but not multiplicative inverses.  If you regard $\mathbb R^2$ as the complex numbers then you can use the field structure on $\mathbb C$ if you like.

Comment: What you have written makes no sense. Vectors do not have denominators and you cannot multiply them. Your $v$ is not a unit vector. Please [edit] the question to clarify. Show us exactly what geogebra is telling you - both input and output.

Comment: Combinations of $i$ and $j$ could have multiplicative inverses as quaternions, not vectors, and by the way $\vec i+\vec j $ is not a unit vector